# Ruby on Rails, add a selector from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, selector

I'm trying to display a selector in my **Member** view with data i have in **Payment** model. I tried creating a variable type Payment and passing it to the form. but does'nt work.

```
 <%= form_for (@member) do |f| %>
    <div class="fiel">
      <%= f.select :payments, Payment::MEMBERSHIP%>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using a space between `form_for` and `(@member)`. Unlike many languages where the space is optional, it actually changes the meaning of your method invocation in Ruby. Use `form_for(@member)` or `form_for @member`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
<%= f.select :payments, options_for_select(Payment::MEMBERSHIP) %>
```